# expected ‘voidpc’ but argument is of type ‘double’

Tags: c, linux, zlib

```
builtin-stat.c: In function ‘abs_printout’:
builtin-stat.c:1023:5: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘gzwrite’
     gzwrite(trace_file, avg, sizeof(avg));
     ^
In file included from builtin.h:6:0,
                 from builtin-stat.c:45:
/usr/include/zlib.h:1341:21: note: expected ‘voidpc’ but argument is of type ‘double’
 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzwrite OF((gzFile file,
```

What is a `voidpc` type? never heard of that. zlib.h tells me that it is z_void. What does it mean? and should i typecast here?

WARNINGS:

```
 CC       builtin-stat.o
builtin-stat.c: In function ‘abs_printout’:
builtin-stat.c:1020:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     int written = gzwrite(trace_file, (void *) &avg, sizeof(avg));
     ^
builtin-stat.c:1024:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
         fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write %d to file\n", avg);
         ^
builtin-stat.c:1026:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fclose’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
             fclose(trace_file);
             ^
In file included from util/util.h:45:0,
                 from builtin.h:4,
                 from builtin-stat.c:45:
/usr/include/stdio.h:237:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘gzFile’
 extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
            ^
builtin-stat.c:1029:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Passed %d bytes, wrote %d\n", sizeof avg, written);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `voidpc` is a typedef: `typedef void const * voidpc`. you can find the zlib typedefs and the like in the `zconf.h` header file, which the `zlib.h` header in turn requires.
[source of `zconf.h` here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/labs/axmake/trunk/src/libuc++/srclib/zlib/zconf.h)

A typecast here would not do the trick, I think. The error is saying that `avg` is of the type `double`. `gzwrite` takes uncompressed data, processes it byte-per-byte and writes a number of bytes to the target file. A pointer allows `gzwrite` to cast to a `char *`, and set about its business easily. Just pass a pointer, optionally cast it to a `voidpc` or `void *`, and _check the return value:

```
int written = gzwrite(
    trace_file,
    (void *) &avg,
    sizeof(avg)
);
if (written == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write %f to file\n", avg);
    if (trace_file)
        gzclose(trace_file);
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
printf("Passed %llu bytes, wrote %d\n", sizeof avg, written);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah so, when I change it to gzwrite(trace_file, &avg, sizeof(double));

there is no error. but it is not being written to the file.

Comment: @pistal: what's the return value? `gzwrite` returns the number of bytes written, or -1 on error

Comment: How do I check the return value?

Comment: @pistal: added that to my answer just now: `gzwrite` returns an int, which indicates errors (-1 => something went wrong), or the number of bytes that were written to the file

Comment: Passed 8 bytes, wrote 8. But the file size is Zero. Don't understand why!

Comment: Whne I do a printf("%f", avg); I see the output.

Comment: Did you run your program using a debugger? @pistal

Comment: @pistal: how are you closing the file pointer? `gzclose` should be used. Also check the errors with `gzerror`, and always clear the errors before continuing using `gzclearerr`...

Comment: I'm cloing the file using gzclose. i'll check for error please wait a bit.

ALK: yes.

Comment: @pistal: whatever the debugger showed, I'd consider that useful information, because all we have to go on is a simple compiler error...

Comment: Yes. But there arn't any error. just 2 warnings. where do you want me to paste them?

Comment: @pistal: Edit your question, add the warnings there, too

Comment: Added all the warnings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55434/discussion-between-pistal-and-elias-van-ootegem).

Comment: The file was getting rewritten everytime. that's the reason it was empty!